# How to get VS2010 not show useless information in the Methods dropdown?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have an app with a ton of UI components on the form.  As a result, when I drop down the Methods (?) combobox, there are a ton of irrelevant entries.

[image]

Is there a setting somewhere that limits the list to actual code constructs (e.g. methods/events/etc...)?

Comment: This is one of the reasons I never use these ComboBoxes. I just use "go to definition", "find references" and I group my controls into Usercontrols. Oh and I stopped using Forms and use WPF (no code behind)

Answer (score 2):

Don't know how to do this with the drop down but maybe an extension would help you out.

You could use something like the [VS10x Code Map](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1c54d1bd-d898-4705-903f-fa4a319b50f2?SRC=Home):

[image: VS10x Code Map]

The [Solution Navigator](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef?SRC=Home) also groups items by type rather than alphabetically:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The only setting I can find that affects the "Navigation Bar" is to hide/show, located in Tools/Options/Text Editor/[Your Language]/General at the bottom under the display heading, "Navigation Bar" check box.

Some ideas:
1) You could define all of your event handlers and additional methods in a subclass, then a single method in your parent class to connect everything up to a private member of the subclass type.  When in the subclass, only the subclass methods would show up in the navigation bar.
2) You could derive a class from your main form class, setting anything you needed to see in the derived class as protected in the base class (such as the event handlers).  This would also effectively filter your navigation bar.

HTH